# Getting two vertical scroll bars and horizontal scroll bar not showing

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

I've read a lot of answers for this question online, tried everything from doing `overflow-y:hidden`, to `overflow-x:scroll;white-space:nowrap` but nothing works:

```
<html style="height: 100%;">

    <head lang="en">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Titler </title>
        <script src="../dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js?ignore=notused30"></script>
        <script src="sorting.js"></script>

    </head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0px;">

   <center>

           <div style="font-style:bold;font-size:30;color:black;"> DM </div>
<BR>
   <font size="2" color="red"> <a href="ag-grid_selector.jsp">  UPDATE  </a>        </font  >
   </center>


<BR></center></br>
<div>
        <center><span style="padding-bottom: 4px; display: inline-block;">
            <button onclick="buyside()">Buy</button>
            <button onclick="sellside()">Sell</button>
            <button onclick="clearFilters()">Clear Filters</button>

        </span><center>


        </div>

        <div id="myGrid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0px" class="ag-fresh"></div>       

  </body>

</html>
```

But I'm getting double vertical scrollbars are shown in the images, and the horizontal scroll bar appears only after scrolling down the outside vertical scrollbar which is an inconvenience. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Changes in line 10 :

```
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
```

```html
   <html style="height: 100%;">

       <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>Titler </title>
           <script src="../dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js?ignore=notused30"></script>
           <script src="sorting.js"></script>

       </head>
   <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">

      <center>

              <div style="font-style:bold;font-size:30;color:black;"> DM </div>
   <BR>
      <font size="2" color="red"> <a href="ag-grid_selector.jsp">  UPDATE  </a>        </font  >
      </center>


   <BR></center></br>
   <div>
           <center><span style="padding-bottom: 4px; display: inline-block;">
               <button onclick="buyside()">Buy</button>
               <button onclick="sellside()">Sell</button>
               <button onclick="clearFilters()">Clear Filters</button>

           </span><center>


           </div>

           <div id="myGrid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0px" class="ag-fresh"></div>       

     </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: But that just gives me a vertical scroll bar inside the table, so then it can be scrolled below (like infinitely below the page). And there's a lot of data, so there's no way to get the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: hmm! Please and all codes here: https://jsfiddle.net/ if it is possible!

Comment: Okey! See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB_jZuHnLAg It is in the Arabic language but very useful!